# How to Deal with Low Quality Content (Without Deleting or Adding More Content)?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, noindex

I have around 95% low quality articles in my web site. I don't need to delete them because those are for users. I don't want to search engine traffic also those articles. Those articles just for loyal readers to read after visiting my site. So I can't delete them and those have just around 50 words per artciles and I don't want to add more also.

**And I never want to SEO traffic for those low quality articles.**

But other 5% articles are really high quality and **I am targeting SEO traffic for them**.

But **I don't want to affect those quality articles from low quality one**.

So I can no-index adding `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` for those low quality articles. Is it enough? Or I have to do something more? Or is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how may articles there are, however based on this article https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag using the meta-tag is enough.  Whether you can add them to all your pages is another story.

However it will only work with well behaved spiders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

There will be nearly 20-30 quality articles when starting and then there will be added 1-4 articles per month. 

There are 1000+ low quality articles and every day adding nearly about 10-50 low quality articles.

Comment: Your question was "is it enough" the answer above shows it is...but that doesn't mean it will be easy to implement.

Comment: What do you mean by "However it will only work with well behaved spiders."?

Comment: Search engine crawlers are also known as spiders (because they crawl around the web, get it?).  Not all of them behave the rules.